# What to do after killing dragon?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

So I'm about to beat the ender dragon and "finish the game". Aside from the Wither, what other goals should i accomplish in Minecraft?

Comment: Nothing, the game is widely known for not having a big storyline, in fact you have one mission, which is to slay the Ender Dragon.

However the game gives you freedom to do anything you want, which can be literally everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up goals yourself, for example:

- Build a fully powered beacon tower
- Automating stuff
- Go find an end ship, grab the elytra, and fly to the world border
- Share to the world your experience

Comment: I meant any other structures (OTHER than the end ship) that i could explore (im on xbox)